# Is there an equivalent to scala's monadic-for/yield syntax in ceylon?

Tags: ceylon

How can one achieve a ¨monadic for/yield¨ syntax in Ceylon, e.g. for trampolining, since Ceylon does not perform tail call optimization. The for/yield-syntax requires the introduction of new variable names which is not possible using Tree-like syntax.

What is the best way to simulate Scala's for/yield in Ceylon?

One solution would be to use a (typed) map. This feels a bit like creating an internal (typed) scripting language based on maps like Python.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, since:

1. Ceylon, like Java, simply doesn't do tail recursion optimization. It's not a matter of doing it "right" or "wrong"; it's something the compiler simply doesn't do at all.
2. There is simply no built-in `Monad` abstraction in Ceylon. One can write one's own `Monad` type using the experimental support for type functions, but it's not a part of the Ceylon language module or SDK.
3. Ceylon [comprehensions](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.2/tour/comprehensions/) (which are sorta very roughly similar to Scala's `for`/`yield`) are defined to range over streams, not over monads.

So I guess the direct answer to your question is "no". There is no equivalent.

To give a more helpful answer to your question, I would have to know what you are actually trying to achieve here. It's really hard to imagine how the need for tail call optimization could have arisen when working with Ceylon's built-in streams, sequences, collections, or tuples. None of these constructs were designed to be iterated via recursion, since recursion is just not efficient on the JVM. So you must be trying to do something different, but I'm not sure what that might be.

Comment: I fully agree that recursion isnt necessary in ceylon. But it is possible. And it can cause stackoverflow exception which is at odds with the tremedous effort taken to eliminate most possibilities of runtime errors in ceylon. On the other hand, scala`s for/yield is helpful in writing legible code. Take as an example an logical unification and substitution algorithm or simplier mapping from one to another tree. In my opinion it would be a logical consequence from your answer to completely exclude direct and indirect recursion and treat it as an error being not necessary but risky.

Comment: Sure, I mean, I agree that tail recursion would be nice. But it seems to me that the best place to implement that would be in the VM itself. Or perhaps even as a language-independent bytecode post-processor, since the problem just doesn't seem language-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Noted [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html):

> Scala’s “for comprehensions” are syntactic sugar for composition of multiple operations with foreach, map, flatMap, filter or withFilter.

So, given that Scala's for comprehensions are syntactic sugar, they can be easily simulated in Ceylon by performing the translations shown on the linked page.

That being said, Ceylon and Scala are different languages with different features, and that leads to different "best" ways of accomplishing similar tasks. So, just because you *can* simulate certain Scala features in Ceylon doesn't mean that you *should*. It really depends on the actual problem you are trying to solve.